# Is there a rule in eslint to deny "assign, then return" pattern?

Tags: typescript, return, eslint, static-analysis

I want to deny using the following pattern in code:

```
function do_something_bad() {
    // bad
    const x = do_something_else();
    return x;
}

function do_something_good() {
    // good
    return do_something_else();
}
```

It looks very weird for me, and is purely style issue, so eslint should be a good way to handle it (I'm open to suggestions, any other linter is also OK, I just have eslint configured, so ask about it). Is there any rule (or maybe plugin) I can install/enable to require only the "Good" option?

For background, I'm mostly python man, and it is inspired by `flake8` R504 (from [`flake8-return`](https://github.com/afonasev/flake8-return) plugin) error. It is also present in [`tslint` Microsoft extensions](https://github.com/Microsoft/tslint-microsoft-contrib), but they are "archived and read-only" (rule `no-unnecessary-local-variable`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research I found out that ["sonarjs"](https://github.com/SonarSource/eslint-plugin-sonarjs) ESLint plugin has `prefer-immediate-return` rule (enabled by default) for exactly this case. Running eslint with this plugin reveals all such usages (as well as some other style defects).

*(I'm not affiliated in any way with this plugin)*